# LinearRegression in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a question regarding the LinearRegression model in scikit learn

(http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)

If we run the following code:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates   = pd.date_range('20000101', periods=100)
df      = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
df['A'] = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100))  
df['B'] = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100))
df['C'] = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100))
df['D'] = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100))  
df['E'] = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100))
df['F'] = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100))

y       = ['A','B','C']
x       = ['D','E','F']


ols     = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept = True, 
                                        normalize     = True, 
                                        copy_X        = True, 
                                        n_jobs        = 1)

ols.fit(df[x],df[y])
```

What is this ols doing here?

Is it running 3 different OLS regressions? Meaning,

1) an OLS of `df['A']` with  `df[['D','E','F']]`

2) an OLS of `df['B']` with `df[['D','E','F']]`
and

3) an OLS of `df['C']` with `df[['D','E','F']]`

Or is it running a single OLS of `df[['A','B','C']]` with `df[['D','E','F']]` (I think this is called SUR? not sure...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some tests to understand this case.

After running your code,

```
ols.coef_
array([[-0.5273036 ,  0.56382854,  0.24751725], # train for 'A'
       [-0.10430077,  0.10671576,  0.18554053],  # train for 'B'
       [ 0.01481826,  0.03811442,  0.75333578]]) # train for 'C'
```

We can see the coef contains 3 arrays and each array has three parameters.

Then we run

```
a = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept = True, 
                                        normalize     = True, 
                                        copy_X        = True, 
                                        n_jobs        = 1)
a.fit(df[x],df['A'])
a.coef_
array([-0.5273036 ,  0.56382854,  0.24751725])
```

which gives us the same coef as the first array we got above

```
a.fit(df[x],df['B'])
a.coef_
array([-0.10430077,  0.10671576,  0.18554053])
```

which gives us the same coef as the second array we got above and so on.

Therefor, when you call `ols.fit(df[x],df[y])`, it creates three different linear regressions for your three target output `y`

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if scikit learn has something like a "single" OLS? I believe in statsmodels is called "Seemingly Unrelated Regression" but can't find it in scikit-learn

Comment: sorry, i never used this model and sklearn does not have this. Maybe you can try `scikits.statsmodels` that contains SUR